# Event triggered infinite times when scroll reaches a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have several divs one below another, all of them have a huge height and  have an element inside being animated. The animation of the content of every div occurs at the same time but since they are one below another only the animation of the element of the first div can be seen, and when scrolling down to the next ones, the animation has already happened and they look as if they were not animated.

I found here a similar question and found a snippet, I modified it so that the event occurs just once (this is what I want to achieve), and since the event occurs when the targeted element is reached while scrolling, it keeps happening when the condition is false, here's the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var chart2T = $('#chartdiv2').offset().top,
    chart2H = $('#chartdiv2').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (chart2T+chart2H-wH)){

        do{
            alert('secondChart on the view!');
        }
            while( 1 > 2 )
    }
});
```

with the do while I wanted to ensure the event was triggered just once, but I haven't been able to achieve it. Can you lend me some help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a flag to state whether the event has been triggered already or not?

```
var alertShown = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var chart2T = $('#chartdiv2').offset().top,
    chart2H = $('#chartdiv2').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (chart2T+chart2H-wH) && !alertShown){ // check if alert was not already triggered

        do{
            alert('secondChart on the view!');//alert triggered once
            alertShown = true; // now it will no longer trigger
        }
            while( 1 > 2 )
    }
});
```

The idea is that you're making `alertShown` have a scope outside the `scroll` function, so that it's state exists even after the function ends.